# SQL Query for XML Type

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT   employeeName
  FROM   XMLTABLE (xmlnamespaces (
                      'http://urn:global:cs:common' AS "tns0") , '/tns0:organization/tns0:employee' PASSING XMLType 
                      ((select a.EmployeeXML from impp.Employee a))
                      COLUMNS
                      employeeName NUMBER PATH 'tns0:EmployeeDetails/@value'
                       ) xmlT;
```

It shows an exception

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has this nice feature of doing a lateral-view join when you write a regular cartesian product to an `xmltable(...)`.

Try it this way:

```
SELECT xmlT.employeeName
FROM impp.Employee A
    XMLTABLE(
        xmlnamespaces('http://urn:global:cs:common' AS "tns0"),
        '/tns0:organization/tns0:employee'
        PASSING XMLType(A.EmployeeXML)
        COLUMNS
            employeeName NUMBER PATH 'tns0:EmployeeDetails/@value'
    ) xmlT;
```

**Notes:**

- It appears that your `impp.Employee.EmployeeXML` is a CLOB column. That's why this code will work OK. If the `EmployeeXML` is an XmlType column instead, just leave the "typecast" to XmlType out of the query.

**And since you're new to stackoverflow.com...**

- If the code is not working, comment on the resulting errors and I'll correct it.
- If the code is working, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark.